# Do Player Characters with a powerful build deal more melee damage like a monster would?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, house-rules, goliath

I have a player in one of the games I'm running that's a Goliath Paladin. He uses a greataxe and recently asked me if he could deal more damage like a "Large" monster could since he has a powerful build.

The following is quoted from p.278 of the DMG:

> Big monsters typically wield oversized weapons that deal extra dice of damage on a hit. Double the weapon dice if the creature is Large, triple the weapon dice if the creature is Huge, quadruple the weapon dice if it's Gargantuan...

So since he counts as one size larger than medium, I thought that this rule could apply to him. However, the powerful build mechanic only states:

> You count as one size larger **when determining your carrying capacity and the weight you can push, drag, or lift**.

My players are usually good, and don't try to "break the game", but before I make a decision, I would like to know what a community of other players and GMs would think about this. Would he be able to deal extra damage?

Comment: Are you asking whether powerful build causes PC's to deal more damage or are you asking whether a houserule along those lines would imbalance the game and cause issues? (I suggest asking the latter, as if it powerful build already does this, then no houserule would be required, which answers would point out)

Comment: Note, I have tagged this question as being [dnd-5e] because you directly quote the DMG and Powerful Build and have used the term "5e", but in the future, remember to include system tags so that we know what game you are taking about.

Comment: You're asking if giving a player double damage dice, effectively for free, is unbalanced?

Comment: Seems like this is fully answered by [Are Goliaths able to wield large-sized weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58816/28941)

Comment: Shifting this from “Do they get this?” to “But what if they did?” might be an effective strategy here. The accepted answer there opines briefly on the subject but we could provide more thorough, backed up answers on the effects of that ruling. I might also suggest considering a question about asking about the effects of giving them the Rune Knight’s +1d4 for a larger size instead of the doubled dice.

Comment: But closing for now while we clarify what you meant (and feel free to just leave it closed if the other question does answer everything you wanted to know).

Comment: The question hasn't demonstrably changed, so I've closed this again.